# 'NoneType' object is not iterable in AppEngine mail send

Tags: python, google-app-engine

On my local server, I get this error when trying to send a mail

> INFO     2017-03-01 16:54:06,819 mail_stub.py:143] MailService.Send
>    From: None "no-reply@None.appspotmail.com"
>     To: v*****@d******.com
>     Subject: Du contenu arrive à expiration (alldigital@test.gpartner.eu)
>     Body:
>       Content-type: text/plain
>       Data length: 50
>   INFO     2017-03-01 16:54:06,819 mail_stub.py:306] You are not currently sending out real email.  If you have sendmail installed you can use it by using the server with --enable_sendmail
>
> ERROR    2017-03-01 16:48:43,630 wsgi.py:279]  Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>   File "/home/*****/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py",
>   line 268, in Handle
>   for chunk in result:
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

My code is:

```
def send(recipient, subject, body):
    message = mail.EmailMessage(
        sender=u'{} <no-reply@{}.appspotmail.com>'.format(app_identity.get_application_id(),
                                                           app_identity.get_application_id()),
        subject=subject,
        body=body,
        to=recipient
    )
    message.check_initialized()
    message.send()
```

And I have no clue of what's wrong. D you have any to solve this issue or some things I could try to debug ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show the code calling `send()`? The error message is *following* the info msg from `mail_stub.py`, meaning it could actually be caused by something else **after** `send()` completes. Maybe add a debug print after `send()` to check this theory?

Answer (score 1):

Ok my bad. It has nothing to do with the mails, I was just not returning anything at the end of the route handler. The error comes from there. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your logs, this is the sending email address:

> From: None "no-reply@None.appspotmail.com"

I've never used `app_identity.get_application_id()` but it isn't working for you since it return "None".  Rather than delve into that, why not hardcode the app id to see if that fixes the problem, i.e.:

```
sender=u'no-reply@myapp.appspotmail.com'
```

Comment: Actually according to the code it'd be `sender=u'myapp <no-reply@myapp.appspotmail.com>'`, which *might* actually be the problem, if the mail service doesn't support such format. Testing with both variants should clarify.

Comment: I had to write no-reply@None.appspotmail.com between " " and not < > because Stackoverflow was not displaying it (so in my console logs it's between < >)